# Store image (JPEG, PNG, etc.) through GridFS into MongoDB using Angular 2

Tags: mongodb, angular

I want to store an image (only pictures.. and not documents) into MongoDB using GridFS. Please see I used the an npm module to have a picture dragged and dropped as below.

```
<image-upload
            [max]="100"
            [url]="'http://localhost:3000/upload'"
            [headers]="[{header: 'Authorization', value: 'MyToken'}]"
            [buttonCaption]="'Select Images!'"
            [dropBoxMessage]="'Drop your images here!'"
            [maxFileSize]="1048576"
            [extensions]="['jpg', 'png', 'gif']"
            (onFileUploadFinish)="imageUploaded($event)"
            (onRemove)="imageRemoved($event)"
            (isPending)="disableSendButton($event)">

    </image-upload>
```

//Angular code is below

```
export class AlbumComponent{

    upload(event){
        console.log(event);
    }

    imageUploaded(image:any){
        console.log(image);

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data')
        // headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', image.file);

        console.log(formData.get(image));
    }
    imageRemoved(event){

    }
    disableSendButton(event){

    }
}
```

I get the image details in the imageUploaded function... How can I push this to my MongoDB instance?

Comment: If your images are **not** actually all "larger than 16MB each" ( and for the sake of people viewing your webpages then we hope they are not ) then you do not want GridFS. Simply store such data in a property of the related data, since MongoDB does not care if it's binary or whatever. Or indeed just give a filename and store in another service. You should only use GridFS for it's intended purpose. Which is "large" file storage for content greater than 16MB.

Comment: Also. You cannot talk to MongoDB from a browser. So this makes `angular` the most non-descriptive tag you can use in concert. You need to be using another layer here. "nodejs, java, python?" pick one. And please show what work you have done on that side to try and implement what you want to do.

Comment: You're right, right now my image files upload size is limited to 10MB.  I am getting the base64 encoded string of the image in imageUploaded() function, but need inputs how can i push this to mongoDB ? I am exploring the Observables to listen to my event and then push using subscribe. But need pointers